# How can I access the emrfs filesystem from python in pyspark code?

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am using pyspark on amazon EMR and need to access files stored on the emrfs in s3, everywhere I look I can only find examples for how to access the emrfs via the spark API, but I need to access it in the executers, using python code. How can I do that?

Comment: You can use Hadoop FS API for that

Comment: @blackbishop can you please post an example for that so I will accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use [Hadoop FS API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html). From Pyspark you can access it via the JVM.

Here is an example that lists files from S3 bucket folder and prints the paths.

```
Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
conf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()

s3_folder = Path("s3://bucket_name/folder")
gs = s3_folder.getFileSystem(conf).globStatus(s3_folder)

for f in gs:
  print(f.getPath().toString())
```

Not sure why you want to read files this way as you can do that using Spark but here is a way using Hadoop FS `open` method:

```
fs = s3_folder.getFileSystem(conf)
fs_data_input_stream = fs.open(s3_folder)

line = fs_data_input_stream.readLine()
while line:
    print(line)
    line = fs_data_input_stream.readLine()
```

However, if you're using EMR Cluster I recommend copying the files from S3 to the local system and use them.

Comment: I need the emrfs capability to access files without downloading them, Is that possible?

Comment: @thebeancounter What do you mean by "_access files without downloading_"? The above code doesn't download the files...

Comment: this is also not real access to the files, only to the meta data. imaging I would like to use open(path, "r") in my python code and need the file to be accessible via file system

Comment: @thebeancounter you can not do that with Python `os.open` as it is located in distant storage and not on local system. Please check Hadoop [open](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#open(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)) method which does exactly the same

Comment: so this is why I am asking how to use it in python I can not find any reference to it

Answer (score 0):

Below code can help you in listing the content of a bucket in aws using boto3.

```
from boto3.session import Session

ACCESS_KEY='your_access_key'
SECRET_KEY='your_secret_key'

session = Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                  aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
s3 = session.resource('s3')
your_bucket = s3.Bucket('your_bucket')

for s3_file in your_bucket.objects.all():
    print(s3_file.key)
```

Comment: This is regular s3, and you need to download the files locally before you can use them, the entire idea about emrfs is that it allows you to access them as a file system without download

Comment: If you are assessing files using boto3, emrfs will be outof sync with consistency view enabled. Its not a good idea to use boto3 in any of EMR.